# Why does $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k}$ equal 1

Tags: calculus, limits, factorial

Came across this in my maths book.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k} = 1$$

Why is it so?

Comment: Some other posts about the same problem:
[Finding limit of sequence: $\lim _{n \to \infty} {\frac{n!}{n^k(n-k)!}}=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1870858),
[Proof that $\lim\limits_{h \to \infty} \frac{h!}{h^k(h-k)!}=1$ for any $k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/810147),
[Limits involing Factorials $\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{N!}{(N-k)!N^{k}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1330168),
[Why $ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n!}{n^{k}(n-k)! } =1 $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3185830),