# Limits involving factorials $\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{N!}{(N-k)!N^{k}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, factorial

I am trying to calculate the following limit

$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{N!}{(N-k)!N^{k}}$$ where $k$ can be any number between $0$ and $N$.

I thought of the following:

If I take the logarithm of the expression then I get:

$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \left(\log(N!)-\log((N-k)!)-k\log N\right)$$

Using the Stirling formula this can be approximated as:

$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \left(N\log(N)-(N-k)\log(N-k)-k\log N\right)$$

Now there are two cases: If $k$ is $N$, then the second term vanishes and the remaining terms cancel. If $k$ is smaller than $N$, then I can drop the $k$ inside the second logarithm and all the terms cancel.
So the limit $$\lim_{N\to\infty} \log\left(\frac{N!}{(N-k)!N^{k}}\right)=0$$ Which means that:
$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{N!}{(N-k)!N^{k}}=1$$
I don't know if this is mathematically rigorous. Would like some help. Thanks

Comment: $$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\,n^k}=\frac{n^k+\mathcal O(n^{k-1})}{n^k}\ldots$$

Comment: It is not clear what $k$ is. Is a fixed integer number? Does it depends on $N$ instead?

Comment: Presumably $k$ is a fixed value.  As $N \to \infty$, you will eventually have $N \gt k$, so you only have to worry about that case.

Comment: $lim_{N->\infty} log(\frac{N!}{(N-k)!N^{k}}) \neq 0$

Comment: See also:
[Why does $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k}$ equal 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/527002),
[Finding limit of sequence: $\lim _{n \to \infty} {\frac{n!}{n^k(n-k)!}}=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1870858),
[Proof that $\lim\limits_{h \to \infty} \frac{h!}{h^k(h-k)!}=1$ for any $k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/810147),
[Why $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n!}{n^{k}(n-k)! } =1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3185830).

Answer (score 12):

$$\frac{(n!)}{(n-k)!n^k}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots\{n-(k-1)\}}{n^k}=\prod_{0\le r\le k-1}\left(1-\frac rn\right)$$

Comment: Nice solution lab bhattacharjee....

Comment: @juantheron, thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 9):

A (non-rigorous) probabilistic interpretation: There are balls of $n$ different colors, of which we choose $k$. The probability that we choose $k$ different colored balls is
$$\frac{n(n-1)\dots(n-(k-1))}{n^k} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k}.$$
It is intuitively clear that as the number of colors increases, this probability goes to $1$.

Answer (score 5):

I myself just found a better method:

$\frac{N!}{(N-k)!N^k}=\frac{\prod\limits_{i=0}^{k-1} (N-i)}{N^k}$

The top therefore is a polynomial of order k with the highest order having coefficient 1. Therefore all other terms vanish and you are left with 1 as N approaches infinity,

Thanks!

Comment: Good to know that you made it ! Thanks for posting your solution.