# Limit of $\binom{n}{k}/n^k$

Tags: limits, factorial

How to prove that, $n$ approach infinity and $0\leq k\leq n$ :
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{k!}\times\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!\times n^k} = \dfrac{1}{k!}$$

I have no idea to begin the proof...

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: You want an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof or just want to know how to calculate that limit?

Comment: The right side is not equal to $\binom{n}{k}$ by the way. ($n^k$ instead of $k!$)

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt I can´t follow your comment.

Comment: I meant the title, but yeah, now I see that it is true if you multiply them together. Wrong comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!} = n(n-1)\cdots(n-(k+1))$$ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $k$. So you have the limit towards infinity of a rational function whose numerator and denominator have the same degree. Thus the limit is the ratio of the leading coefficients.

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\right)}{n^k} = 1$$

Comment: This rule can be proved or is admitted?

Comment: It is not hard to prove. Here is a link that talks a bit about it: [Link](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~skalyanswamy/13W-3A-limits_to_infinity.pdf)

Comment: Ok thanks, just factor out the leading coefficient and the remainder of polynomial over the coefficient tends to 1?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much.

Comment: For the limit used in this answer, see: [Limits involing factorials $\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{N!}{(N-k)!N^{k}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1330168) and other questions [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1330168).

Answer (score 1):

Quite an overkill, but since $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$, your limit is a consequence of [Gautschi's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98348/how-do-you-prove-gautschis-inequality-for-the-gamma-function).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac n{n-k}=?$$