# Finding limit of sequence: $\lim _{n \to \infty} {\frac{n!}{n^k(n-k)!}}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, factorial

$k$ is nonnegative integer.
I want to show that$$ \lim _{n \to \infty} {\frac{n!}{n^k(n-k)!}}=1$$

My try :

$$ \frac{n!}{n^k(n-k)!} = \frac{n}{n} \frac{n-1}{n} \cdots \frac{n-k+1}{n}$$

I wanted use multiplicative rule

> If $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to b$ , then $a_n b_n \to ab$.

But It is impossible because 
$$ \frac{n!}{n^k(n-k)!} = \frac{n}{n} \frac{n-1}{n} \cdots \frac{n-k+1}{n}$$
It is infinite product.

I want you to help me.

Comment: Why is it an infinite product? There are only $k$ terms.

Comment: Overkill? It is a simple consequence of [Gautschi's inequality](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98348/how-do-you-prove-gautschis-inequality-for-the-gamma-function), since $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$.

Comment: The result after your simplification is a rational function with the degree of the top polynomial matching the degree of the bottom. From here you know that the limit is the ratio of the leading coefficients, and so it is 1.

Comment: A few related posts: [Why does $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k}$ equal 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/527002),
[Proof that $\lim\limits_{h \to \infty} \frac{h!}{h^k(h-k)!}=1$ for any $k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/810147),
[Limits involing Factorials $\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{N!}{(N-k)!N^{k}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1330168),
[Why $ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n!}{n^{k}(n-k)! } =1 $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3185830),

Answer (score 2):

You actually have a product of a **fixed** number of terms. It is not about whether the product is finite or infinite, but whether the number of terms is fixed (i.e. not varying with the limiting variable). More precisely, you want to prove:
$
\def\lfrac#1#2{{\large\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$

> $∀k∈\mathbb{N}\ \left( \lim\limits_{n∈\mathbb{N}→∞} \lfrac{n!}{n^k·(n-k)!} = 1 \right)$.

And this follows from your algebraic decomposition and the following fact for $f : \mathbb{N}×\mathbb{N}→\mathbb{C}$:

> $∀k∈\mathbb{N}\ \left( ∀i∈[1..k]\ \left( \text{$\lim\limits_{n∈\mathbb{N}→∞} f(n,i)$ exists} \right) ⇒ \lim\limits_{n∈\mathbb{N}→∞} \prod\limits_{i=1}^k f(n,i) = \prod\limits_{i=1}^k \lim\limits_{n∈\mathbb{N}→∞} f(n,i) \right)$.

This fact is a formal statement of:

> The limit of a fixed product of terms is equal to the product of their limits if all those limits exist.

And this fact can be easily proven by induction. It should be clear that this does not apply to things like $\lim\limits_{n∈\mathbb{N}→∞} \prod\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{n+i}{n+i-1} = 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Lambda_{n,k}= {\frac{n!}{n^k(n-k)!}}$. You have proved that $$\Lambda_{n,k}=\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}{\left(1-\frac{i}{n}\right)}=\exp{\bigg(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{\log\left(1-\frac{i}{n}\right)}\bigg)}$$
Now we use this :$$\forall x, 0\le x < 1,\quad -x-\frac{x^2}{2}\le \log(1-x)\le-x$$
  $$\exp{\big(-\frac{(k-1)k}{n}-\frac{(k-1)k(2k-1)}{12n^2}\big)}= \exp{\bigg(-\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{\big(\frac{i}{n}+\frac{i^2}{2n^2}}\big)\bigg)}\le   \Gamma_{n,k}\le \exp{\bigg(-\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{\frac{i}{n}}\bigg)}=  \exp{\bigg(-\frac{(k-1)k}{n}\bigg)}$$
Finally both side tends to $1$.