# Why $ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n!}{n^{k}(n-k)! } =1 $?

Tags: limits, factorial

I was on [brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/problems/binomial-distribution-at-infinity/) learning probability. There was a process explaining how the distribution of a Poisson Random Variable can be obtained from a Binomial Random Variable.

Consider the binomial distribution:

$$
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
P(X=k) &={\binom n k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}\\
  &=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
$$
Substitute $m=np$ , or  $p=\frac{m}{n}$ :
$$
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
P(X=k) &=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} \left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^k \left(1-\frac{m}{n}\right)^{n-k}\\
  &=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} \frac{m^k}{n^k} \left(1-\frac{m}{n}\right)^{n}\left(1-\frac{m}{n}\right)^{-k}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
$$
Slightly rearrange
$$
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
&=\frac{n!}{n^k(n-k)!}  \left(1-\frac{m}{n}\right)^{-k}\frac{m^k}{k!}\left(1-\frac{m}{n}\right)^{n}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
$$

> Note that
>   $$
> \begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
> & \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n!}{n^{k}(n-k)! } =1,\quad\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(1-\frac{m}{n}\right)^{-k} =1,\quad  \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(1-\frac{m}{n}\right)^{n} =e^{-m} 
> \end{aligned}\end{equation}
> $$

Thus, we have the final result which is equal to the formula for the Poisson distribution.

$$
=\frac{m^k e^{-m}}{k!}
$$

> In all these steps, what I don't understand is the following limit:
>   $$
>  \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  \frac{n!}{n^{k}(n-k)! } =1
> $$

Comment: There are several posts about this: 
[Why does $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k}$ equal 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/527002),
[Finding limit of sequence: $\lim _{n \to \infty} {\frac{n!}{n^k(n-k)!}}=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1870858),
[Proof that $\lim\limits_{h \to \infty} \frac{h!}{h^k(h-k)!}=1$ for any $k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/810147),
[Limits involing Factorials $\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{N!}{(N-k)!N^{k}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1330168)

Comment: I found the posts in the above comment [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Crightarrow%20%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Bn!%7D%7Bn%5E%7Bk%7D(n-k)!%20%7D%20%3D1%24&p=1). For some useful tips on searching here see: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Comment: Some of the other posts treating the same question painfully lack details and context. Maybe you'd want to put them on hold or close them.

Comment: billyandr: If you actually have a look at those links, you can see that two of those posts are closed (as duplicates) now. Let me also say that the fact that you have added some more context to your question is certainly appreciated. (After all, that's what [lead to reopening](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3185830/revisions).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is rather obvious if you cancel the factorials:

$$\frac{n!}{n^{k}(n-k)! } =\frac{\overbrace{n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)}^{k\; factors}}{n^k}= 1\cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdots \left(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\right)\stackrel{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 1$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know it was right there under my eyes.

Comment: You are welcome. This "not seeing the obvious" just happens once in a while, I think, to all who do maths. So, it is good to have a math platform like this one. :-)

Answer (score 2):

$$a_n=\frac{n!}{n^{k}(n-k)! }\implies \log(a_n)=\log(n!)-k \log(n)-\log((n-k)!)$$

Use Stirling approximation and continue with Taylor series to get
$$\log(a_n)=\frac{k(1-k)}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ Continue with Taylor
$$a_n=e^{\log(a_n)}=1+\frac{k(1-k)}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Comment: This has already a slight touch of overkill, hasn't it? :-)

Comment: @trancelocation. You are totally right for the limit. One of my manias is to always look at the approach to the limit. Have a look at https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/8339/teaching-limits-and-asymptotics-at-the-same-time . Cheers :-)