# Limit question with factorials

Tags: calculus, limits

Can you explain me how to solve $ \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{  n!}{ ((n-k)!.n^k)}$

Comment: Do you mean: $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n!}{(n-k)!\cdot n^k}$$

Comment: Stirling approximation will do.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527002/why-does-displaystyle-lim-n-to-infty-fracnn-knk-equal-1/527003#527003

Answer (score 2):

*Stirling's formula* isn't required:
$$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}=n(n-1)\dotsm(n-k+1)\sim_\infty n^k, \enspace\text{so}\quad\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\,n^k}\sim_\infty\frac{n^k}{n^k}=1. $$

Comment: that's right. I got a little bit confused to see if the decomposition of the n! would be k  times or k+1 times

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!\cdot n^k}=\dfrac{\prod_{r=0}^{k-1}(n-r)}{n^k}=\prod_{r=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\dfrac rn\right)$$